# infinite loop rendering higher order component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

What's wrong with below code? Doesn't seems ok when I got infinite loop but couldn't figure why.

```
export default function ProtectRoute(EnhancedComponent) {
  @connect(state=>state.something,{callAPI})
   class myClass extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.callAPI()
    }

    render() {

      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  return myClass
}
```

I use my above code like so, in route I do
`<Route exact path='/app' component={ProtectRoute(App)} />`

Comment: Why do you pass `{callAPI}` as second parameter of the connect?

Comment: @ChrisR so that I can access it via this.props

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: If `callAPI` triggers a parent rerender, this will loop. Try declaring `const ProtectedApp = ProtectRoute(App);` outside of any class, and use it as `<Route exact path='/app' component={ProtectedApp}/>`.